# javascript array multidimensional using split to a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, split, push

Hello I'm new student in js, I'm trying to use `split` in `output[2]` so i can take the Month's number `dd-mm-YYYY` and using `push`  to a `new array` to save em with a new name of months (str ?) .

ex: 21/`05`/1989 with a new name of month in a new array : `May`

```js
var output = [ 
    [ '0001', '0002', '0003', '0004' ],   
    [ 'Roman Alamsyah', 'Dika Sembiring', 'Winona', 'Bintang Senjaya' ],
    [ '21/05/1989', '10/10/1992', '25/12/1965', '13/9/1994', '10/8/1994', '19/7/1994' ],
] ;

function mixarray(){

var months =[]; //probably wrong should just push to new array in output ?
  //months.push([]);
  //console.log(output[2].length);

  for(var i = 0; i < output.length  ;i ++){
   // console.log(output[i]);
    
    for(var j=0 ; j< output[i].length; j++){ 
      months = output[i][j].split("/");
    }
  }
console.log(months);  
}

mixarray(output);
```

I did some split  but somehow my brain crashed after trying to push em to new array and combine it with month's name(probably using `if-else` for `month's name` huh ?)
it might better to push in `new-array in output` 
so it will show like this later with `sorted` ( i can do the sort later ) :

```
Months:
August,Dec,July,May,Oct,Sept
```

I just need to know how this months be able to push into a new array :

```
['May','Oct','Dec','Sept','August','July'];
```

from this :

```
[ '21/05/1989', '10/10/1992', '25/12/1965', '13/9/1994', '10/8/1994', '19/7/1994' ]
```

Comment: You are overwriting value of `months` in every iteration of the loop when you use `months = `. End result will be `months` is the same as the  split in last iteration

Comment: you want to create a new array of months or replace content of output[2] with months?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple proof of concept:

```js
var monthMap = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sept","Oct","Nov","Dec"];

// output [2]
var fullArr = [ '21/05/1989', '10/10/1992', '25/12/1965', '13/9/1994', '10/8/1994', '19/7/1994' ];

var monthArray = fullArr.map(function(v) {
  var numericMonth = Number(v.split('/')[1]);
  
  return monthMap[numericMonth - 1];
});

console.log(monthArray); // ["May", "Oct", "Dec", "Sept", "Aug", "Jul"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the dates will always be in the third array in the `output` variable, then you can skip the nested loop

```
const MONTHS = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
output = [[],[],[ '21/05/1989', '10/10/1992', '25/12/1965', '13/9/1994', '10/8/1994', '19/7/1994' ]]
let months = [],
    length = output[2].length;
for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
  var elem = output[2][i];
  months.push(MONTHS[elem.split('/')[1]-1]);
}

console.log(months);
```

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript**

```js
// Need the names of the months tied to array to pull names
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

// This is your input (not sure why it is named output)
var output = [ 
    [ '0001', '0002', '0003', '0004' ],   
    [ 'Roman Alamsyah', 'Dika Sembiring', 'Winona', 'Bintang Senjaya' ],
    [ '21/05/1989', '10/10/1992', '25/12/1965', '13/9/1994', '10/8/1994', '19/7/1994' ],
];
  
// Converts DD/MM/YYYY to a JavaScript date object
function toDate(dateStr) {
    var parts = dateStr.split("/");
    return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);
}

// Pass in an array of date strings DD/MM/YYYY
// Returns: An Array of Month Strings
function mixArray(arr){
  var output = [];
  for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++){
    output.push(monthNames[(toDate(arr[i])).getMonth()]);
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(mixArray(output[2]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
function mixarray(){

  var months =[]; 

  for(var i = 0; i < output.length  ;i ++){
   // console.log(output[i]);

     for(var j=0 ; j< output[i].length; j++){
       var parts = output[i][j].split("/");

       if (parts.length === 3) { 
          months.push(output[i][j].split("/")[1])
       }
    }
  }
   console.log(months);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the for loop length with second index of the `output` array.And compare the index with `month` array .Then print the exact month of the array.These all the month push into `newmonths` array

```js
var output = [ 
        [ '0001', '0002', '0003', '0004' ],   
        [ 'Roman Alamsyah', 'Dika Sembiring', 'Winona', 'Bintang Senjaya' ],
        [ '21/05/1989', '10/10/1992', '25/12/1965', '13/9/1994', '10/8/1994', '19/7/1994' ],
    ] ;
      var month=['jan' ,'feb','mar','aprl','may','jun','july','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'];
   function mixarray(){
       var   newmonths =[];
         for(var j=0 ; j< output[2].length; j++){ 
              var mon = output[2][j].split('/');
              newmonths.push(month[mon[1]-1])
              }
          console.log(newmonths)
        }
   mixarray(output);
```